# Web page works fine in local host but not when i host it in google drive

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

The following code as mentioned in the title works fine when i run it from from my browser (as local host) but when i try to run the same web page  from the file I have posted in google drive it doesnt work properly. It seems like the page is loaded correctly(in apearance) but it does not function anymore.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ESP8266 LED Control</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- in the <button> tags below the ID attribute is the value sent to the arduino -->

<button id="11" class="led">Toggle Pin 11</button> <!-- button for pin 11 -->
<button id="12" class="led">Toggle Pin 12</button> <!-- button for pin 12 -->
<button id="13" class="led">Toggle Pin 13</button> <!-- button for pin 13 -->

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".led").click(function(){
            var p = $(this).attr('id'); // get id value (i.e. pin13, pin12, or pin11)
            // send HTTP GET request to the IP address with the parameter "pin" and value "p", then execute the function
            $.get("http://78.87.xx.xx:337/", {pin:p}); // execute get request
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is suposed to send a GET request to the IP address with a specific parameter i.e GET /?LED1=on HTTP/1.1 after every button press, but there is nothing comming in the listener side (http://78.87.xx.xx:337/).

Comment: Might be cross platform issue.

Comment: My first thought is that it's not actually including the jquery.min.js file.  Try linking that to a jQuery CDN and see if that helps

Comment: I've tried linking the jquery file from different sources but it still didn't work.

Comment: Which error do you see in the browsers JS console? I bet there is some error on a “cross domain” issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send AJAX request to another domain/IP per default in all browsers. Those restrictions are turned off when browsing in the localhost/127.0.0.1 context.

If you want to sent a request to another domain/IP you have to enable [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or you have to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. CORS explains everything. I'm trying to make it work using JSONP as you suggested.